Algorithm help: given n sets of integers and a target integer, find a set of one element from each set that adds to the target integer
I have multiple sets of integers, let's call them K_1 through K_N.  Each set is finite and not necessarily the same size.  I have a target integer, C.
Is there a way to select one element from each set such that the sum of those elements is equal to C?
Example:
K_1 = {10, 15, 20}
K_2 = {7, 11, 12, 13}
K_3 = {8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18}
C = 30
Two possible answers: (10, 12, 8), (10, 7, 13)
(Goal is not to find the number of ways, goal is to find at least one way to do it)
I've been struggling with ways to do it that aren't just brute force.  Any insight?  Assume each set is provided as a sorted array.
Edit: all elements are non-negative

Is there a limit on the value of C?

Track the difference. If you choose 20 from the first set, you can ignore numbers greater than 10 from the next set. Then since the numbers are sorted, you don't need to iterate the whole set

This is an NP hard problem as you can reduce subset sum to it. But you can solve it in pseudo-poly time using the same dynamic programming trick as in subset sum.

@OneCricketeer, as I understand there is no assurance the integers are non-negative.

It could be formulated as a 0-1 linear program. Suppose Nij is the value of the jth element of set i. Then let the variable Xij equal 1 if element j of set i is used, else equal 0. Then require Xij summed over j to equal 1, for all i and that NijXij summed over all i and j to equal C. The objective function is arbitrary as only a feasible solution is desired.

@CarySwoveland I would naturally do this with dynamic programming. But I know that 0-1 linear solvers are amazing. Do you have any insight on the relative efficiency of the two approaches?

@btilly, one never knows how long it will take to reach an optimum with an integer, linear program (compared to an LP, for example). It of course depends on the general efficiency of the solver package used and in this case on how tightly the solution is constrained. On the one hand modelling it this way is fast and easy, when compared to a crafting and testing a DP solution, but on the other the ILP solver may seemingly grind away forever when a DP model might solve very quickly. I should also confess that it's been many moons since I was up to speed on the literature.

I've never had success with ILP solvers and numerical combinatorial problems -- by which I mean that they work, but are typically much slower than even relatively naive searches. My guess it that that the near-solutions of problems like these don't form a nice region in the parameter space, so the ILP ends up effectively just an inefficient enumeration of many of the potential solutions. I'd be curious if there's actual literature or writeups from someone who actually knows this stuff.

Sam, you should indicate, with an edit, whether all elements are guaranteed to be non-negative.

@CarySwoveland yes, I wrote an answer some hours ago.

(In this answer, I'm assuming all the integers in the K_i are positive -- if they're not, and -k is the smallest integer appearing, add k+1 to each integer, and (k+1)*N to C).
This problem is NP hard. Because if you have a non-zero subset sum problem (that is, you're given a set {a1, a2, .., an} and want to know if there's a subset that sums to T>0, then you can reduce it to this problem: let K_i be the set {0, ai} and a solution picking one element from each K_i is equivalent to finding a subset of {a1, a2, ..., an}. (There's also a reduction of the zero subset sum problem to this, but it's not quite as neat).
Subset sum has a pseudo-polynomial time solution, using dynamic programming based on the idea that the partial sums can add up only to integers in the range 0...C. This problem has a similar pseudo-polynomial time solution that runs in O(C*sum|K|) and is relatively simple  -- most of the code is  reconstructing the elements that have the right sum once a possible solution is found:
def solve(sets, C):
    path = [{0: None}]
    for k in sets:
        path.append(dict((c+x, x) for c in path[-1] for x in k if c + x <= C))

    if C not in path[-1]:
        return None
    result = []
    for p in reversed(path[1:]):
        result.append(p[C])
        C -= p[C]
    return result[::-1]

K1 = [10, 15, 20]
K2 = [7, 11, 12, 13]
K3 = [8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18]

print(solve([K1, K2, K3], 30))

The idea behind the algorithm is simple: keep a set of possible totals from the first i sets, and from this and the values in K[i+1] construct a new set. If existence of a solution was all that was necessary, that would be it. Specifically, this code determines if there's a solution:
def has_solution(sets, C):
    totals = {0}
    for k in sets:
        totals = {c+x for c in totals for x in k}
    return C in totals

But to reconstruct a solution, the full algorithm uses a dict/map (instead of sets) with key a possible total, and value one element of K[i+1] that can be used to get to that total. This enables one to reconstruct a full solution by going backwards through the dicts in path, subtracting a known k from tht total until you have an element from each K[i] (and by construction have reduced the total to 0).
The full algorithm also avoids totals that are larger than C -- a simple optimization if all the elements in the sets are non-negative.

This implementation has an extra factor of n due to array copying.

@btilly which array copy do you mean? There's four-- one when the path list causes a reallocation when appending, and three when the solution is reconstructed, but I don't think any of these affect efficiency in any significant way (and I don't believe cause a factor of n).

I suggest you display the solution for your example. If K1 = [10,15,20], K3 = K2 = K1 and C = 47 there is no way to select one element from each of the three collections that sum to C. Is that what you obtain? Similarly, what if C = 20 (which has no solution)? Note the question requires that one element be selected from each set.

@CarySwoveland The code is right, but I don't want the answer to be bogged down with test cases. You can play with the code here if you want to play around: https://www.online-python.com/vXmoApYWaC

Thanks, Paul. I don't know Python but should be able to figure out what you are doing.

@CarySwoveland I added some words to try to describe the algorithm.

@PaulHankin I had misread the code. I thought that the DP structure had arrays of how you got there, rather than being a dictionary through which you can reconstruct the path. I have no idea how I misread it that way, but you're clearly right.
